# Why apple login sheet in iOS 13 shows `null` as the app name

Tags: ios, authentication, ios13

Within the application's webview I open the apple page for login. In the app, the iOS system knows it comes from apple so the action sheet shows up for biometric authentication.
All good and all works fine. I can authenticate myself and I will be successfully logged in. The icon in the action sheet is loaded from the app, but ***the app name is not present. Instead it shows null.***

Currently I tried to

- add title to navigation item,
- add title to web view controller within the navigation
- the webview title however is empty. It is out of my scope to set this up, because the webpage comes from apple.
- I added `App Name` to WKWebView in storyboard (btw, I can't seem to figure out what exactly is App Name in this case as WKWebView doesn't seem to have any reference in the code and no documentation)

As far as I know the icon in the action sheet is loaded from the application, so I would believe the name would also be loaded from the app.

Please see the screen view.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution or work around for this?

Comment: Also having an issue with this? :(

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: did you find the solution?